# Can I use my company name instead of using ofbiz logo and name

Tags: apache-license

Sorry this is not a programming questions. My company is looking to do some work on ofbiz. I read the license of apache and I am not sure if its legal to change the logo to our company logo.

http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN

Comment: Not an answer (more of a guess): You do need to provide attribution (somehow), and it would be a good idea to use both the ofbiz logo and the Apache Foundation one there, but I don't think there's a problem if you market your project under your own logo. Just make sure it's extremely obvious that you've build it on top of ofbiz.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about branding, not about software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first paragraph = IANAL.disclaimer()

Apache has a page devoted to how to do branding with [Apache](http://www.apache.org/foundation/marks/pmcs.html).